# How is the heapsize setting for a CF Liberty instance with a particular memory limit

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, websphere-liberty, heap-size

For a CF App (Liberty Runtime based) running on bluemix, I have set a MEMORY_LIMIT say 2G. I dont have any JAVA_OPTS set for setting the -Xms and -Xmx values. How is the heapsize memory allotted by bluemix ? Any range it sets by default ?

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Liberty buildpack uses a ratio to calculate the heap size according to your memory limit.

> **heap_size_ratio**   The ratio that is used to calculate the maximum heap
>   size. The default heap size ratio is 0.75 (75% of the total available
>   memory).

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/blob/master/docs/ibm-jdk.md

`new_heap_size = mem * heap_size_ratio`

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/blob/master/lib/liberty_buildpack/jre/ibmjdk.rb#L175